# Find number of swap required to club all greater than $k$?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

> Given an array of  $N$  numbers and a number  $K$, Find the minimum number of swaps required to bring all the numbers greater than or equal to  $K$  together.  Swap here means, swapping value of  $array[i]$  and  $array[j]$, where  $1 ≤ i , j ≤ N$.

We are also given that:

- $1≤N≤10^5$
- $1≤array[i]≤10^5$
- $1≤K≤10^5$

Sample input:

```
5 3

5 2 1 3 4
```

Sample output:

```
1
```

Comment: Nice question! What are your thoughts about the question? Have you tried solving it? Can you think of *any* algorithm?

Comment: This is just a problem dump, which looks taken from a competitive programming site. Please mention your source, and explain how you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes sir its a problem dump....actually i encountered it in a hiring challenge so its not possible to mention the source.

How I attempted to solve is this,I thought of making a list which contains continuous index ranges such that all elements are greater than or equal to k then joining these ranges to form a bigger range.
for example for array 5 2 1 3 4
and k=3
my list would be like {{0,0},{3,4}}  now all i have to do is fill these holes but cant think ahead of this.
here each element of list has starting and ending index of subarray

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You get the minimum number of swaps if you find a range that already contains as many items >= K as possible, and then swap the elements < K in that range with the elements >= K outside the range.

You count how many items are >= K, let's say there are M items >= K. Obviously O (N).

You examine each range of M consecutive items and count how many items are there ≥ K. Let's say the highest number is m items ≥ K. Easily (maybe not obviously) O (N).

And the answer is M - m.

To actually do the swaps, remember which range had m items ≥ K. Then you iterate through that range until you find an item < K, and through the remaining numbers until you find an item >= K, swap them, and repeat this M - m times. Again O (N). Space requirement is O (1).